# Unable to click on link using Link text/Partial Link text using ruby

Tags: ruby, selenium

I am new here and even to `Ruby` and `Selenium`.  I am trying to click a link on web page which has following code:

```
<a> target="mainFrame" href="dynamic_Utility_Index.htm">Dynamic Utilities</a>
```

So basically I want to click on this dynamic utilities.  The script which I have written so far is:

```
    require 'selenium-webdriver'
    require 'win32ole'

    driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for:firefox
    driver.manage().window().maximize();

    driver.navigate.to 'xyz.com'

    wait = Selenium::WebDriver::Wait.new(:timeout =>10) # seconds

    #Click on Dynamic Utilities
    wait.until{driver.find_element(:link_text,'dynamic_Utility_Index.htm').click}
    puts "Clicked"
```

I have even used link, partial_link_text in place of link_text but keep getting the following error

> (Unable to locate element: {"method":"link
>   text","selector":"dynamic"})
>   (Selenium::WebDriver::Error::TimeOutError)

I am using `Ruby` and `Selenium Web driver`.

Comment: Can you check if this link is located inside an iframe? Thanks.

Comment: No its not loctaed within iframe

Answer (score 1):

Did you try with:

```
wait.until{driver.find_element(:link_text,'DYNAMIC UTLITIES').click}
```

?? Sometimes I had to use the text link by capitalized.

Another option could be:

`driver.find_element(:xpath, "//a[contains(@target, 'mainFrame')]").click`

Hope works for you :D

Comment: Tried both, still getting same error..btw thanks for the help

Comment: @JimitShah:

Maybe... as a "debug" mode.... you could do this:

`puts driver.find_elements(:link_text,'DYNAMIC UTLITIES').length`

or 

`puts driver.find_elements(:xpath, "//a[contains(@target, 'mainFrame')]").length`

to see if at least we are able to reach the element. If this give us at least 1 element we can start "playing" with click or text methods.

Comment: I tried both in my code.
Its prints 0 in both the case.

Answer (score 0):

The item you consider to be a `link text` (`dynamic_Utility_Index.htm`) actually just a value of `href` attribute. Actual link text is `"Dynamic Utilities"`. Also you can use `xpath` locator `//a[@href="dynamic_Utility_Index.htm"]` instead of search by link text:

```
wait.until{driver.find_element(:xpath,'//a[@href="dynamic_Utility_Index.htm"]').click}
```

Comment: So you mean like this  wait.until{driver.find_element(:xpath,'/html/body/table/tbody/tr[11]/td[2]/a[@href="dynamic_Utility_Index.htm"]').click}  
wait.until{driver.find_element(:xpath,'/]/a[@href="dynamic_Utility_Index.htm"]').click}  Tried both..same error..Unable to locate element

Comment: Does `wait.until{driver.find_element(:link_text,"Dynamic Utilities").click}` works?

Comment: So i even used  
wait.until{driver.find_element(:xpath,'//a[@href="dynamic_Utility_Index.htm"]').click}

Comment: No It doesn't works, that what i am stuck with..its pretty simple..but i am not able to crack it

Comment: Are you sure that you provided correct `HTML` for target element? It looks like `<a>...>...</a>`, but should looks like `<a...>...</a>`. Maybe you remove something in provided `HTML` code sample

Comment: Its like this 
<a target="mainFrame" href="abc.htm">Dynamic Utilities</a>